# cannot get stream contents - results in internal server error

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I want to verify IPN response from paypal, but for some reason I cannot read the response.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if(!$fp)die();

fputs($fp, $header . $postback);

$res=stream_get_contents($fp); #this triggers 500 error
```

It does open a connection, does `fputs`, but at the last line it hangs up and after some considerable amount of waiting returns `500 error`.

Any ideas what's wrong with it?

**note:** even if I comment the `fputs` line the exactly same thing happens.

Headers:

```
$postback='cmd=_notify-validate&'.http_build_query($_POST);

// build the header string to post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

**Edit**

I tried to use curl, but it always gets me an empty response:

```
$ch = curl_init( 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postback);
$strCurlResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
echo $strCurlResult;
```

The above code outputs nothing at all.

Comment: Something wrong happens on target server. Nobody can help you unless you show headers. I think they are reason of failure.

Comment: use wireshark to inspect the request?

Comment: I see you're using `strlen` that won't give you accurate length in case of unicode encoding. Try using `mb_strlen($postback, 'UTF-8');` instead.

Comment: Tried changing to `mb_strlen($postback,'UTF-8')` and the exactly same thing happens. I think the problem is somewhere else... Even if I comment the fputs line - it gets me the same outcome

Comment: Sounds like `$res=stream_get_contents($fp);` blocks and your request times out. Is there a reason why you're not using [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) for this? I think it would ease everything.

Comment: I tried using curl before but it was returning an empty line, so wanted to try with the above. Could you advice for some equivalent curl that would also use `ssl:`?

Comment: [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279298/curl-request-problem). Lots more on your favourite search engine. Just search for `curl https request` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, but It gets me an empty response, just as before... I will update my answer.

Comment: Try `var_dump($strCurlResult);` It'll give you more details on the return value. (There's a huge difference between false, null and "", but they're all the same printed using echo.)

Comment: Then `var_dump(curl_error($ch))`

Comment: `string(146) "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"`

Comment: I think I'm getting it, Maybe it won't work on my localhost... gotta try from live server, 1 sec.

Comment: yup, it works on the live hosting. lots of thanks!