# Paypal request URL

Tags: php, paypal

Can someone tell me the right URL to use when posting a e.g. pay request to paypal via cURL (in the sandbox).

thanks.

Comment: Have you read PayPal integration documents? Or is taking a shorcut?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here you go;
"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

Comment: really? i thought it was eiter  https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/  or   https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

Comment: my bad if its not url and the CURL then you find you answer here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776827/php-curl-paypal-sandbox

Comment: pay request URL for paypal sandbox is same as i mentioned in my answer!

Comment: tariq; it's not. An Adaptive Payments 'Pay' API call should go to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay, and for Live; https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay

Comment: @Robert i never seen a word Adaptive payments in Question, He is asking URL for the "pay request to paypal while using sandbox account" i practically used it and its working for me, or you better review this https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside

Comment: "..pay request.." - Pay is an Adaptive Payments API call. Hope this clears it up.