# Any alternative to PHP fsockopen() error paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I do get few failures for the IPN notification with fscockopen function. but this happens only once in a while, i doubt its problem in the php configuration.

see the following code, is there a work around for this rather than using the  `PHP fsockopen()` function ? may be CURL ? is this possible to do this in CURL ?

```
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30 );
    if (!$fp) { 
        $this->error_out("PHP fsockopen() error: " . $errstr , "");
    }
```

**Any alternative solution or any robust error checking suggestions ?**

Comment: CURL sounds good to me. You can see this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776827/php-curl-paypal-sandbox

Comment: What's wrong with `fopen('https://www.paypal.com/', 'r');`? Doing it at the socket level is pretty advanced and somewhat pointless given the plethora of HTTP request options PHP provides... Even creating a stream rather than just using `file_get_contents()` is rarely required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html) is working and very useful..it uses curl and if needed we can use the fsock method also.

Very clean script, which makes it easy to understand the parts of a transaction and edit things.